# why am i getting NameError: global name 'spacing' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm getting a NameError: global name 'spacing' is not defined for and im not sure why

```
def main():
    print("Project One\n")
    print("To encrypt message enter: 1")
    print("To decrypt messsge enter: 2\n")
    pick = int(input())
    if pick == 1:
        print("Encrypting!")
        spacing()
    elif pick == 2:
       print("Decrypting!")
    else:
        print("Try again")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


def spacing():
    text = raw_input("Please Enter the message to encrypt: ").upper()
    print(text)
    key = raw_input("Please enter a key to encrypt").upper()
    print(key)
    space_ignore = ""
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if ord(text[i]) == 32:
            space_ignore += " "
        else:
            if j < len(key):
                space_ignore += key[j]
                j += 1
            else:
                j = 0
                space_ignore += key[j]
                j += 1
    print(space_ignore)
    return text, space_ignore
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] in your posts

Answer (score 3):

Python defines are evaluated in-order relative to other statements. By the time `main()` runs, `spacing()` has not yet been defined since control has not yet reached `def spacing(): ...`. Move your `if __name__ == 'main':` block to below the definition of `spacing`.

Answer (score 2):

Put `spacing()` definition above `main` definition and the last thing you need to place is this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

python is a scripting language,would do “line by line” or easy say:from top to end.
make the spacing before main.